# Using inheritance or modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm creating an API wrapper so I've been looking at other libraries to get some ideas on how to structure it. I found that a lot of libraries mix in all their methods in a `Client` class instead of using inheritance.

Why?

Examples:

Octokit: https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/lib/octokit/client.rb

Instagram: https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/blob/master/lib/instagram/client.rb

Twitter (sort of): https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/rest/api.rb

Why not use separate classes?

In Octokit you fetch commits by doing something like

```
client = Octokit::Client.new
client.commits
```

Why not use something like `Octokit::Commit.all`? (Perhaps I'm damaged by Rails and the AR API)

If you mix everything into one big class it seems like you would have issues with accidentally overriding methods all the time.

What do I not understand here? :)

UPDATE:
Here is an example of another library that uses more of an inheritance approach
https://github.com/jeremyw/swish/tree/master/lib/dribbble

Comment: Inheritance forces a class hierarchy on you. Composition does not. I'm not sure I understand your second point; the reason to use instances instead of static methods is because in general it makes things easier if you have an instance.

Comment: Hm, sure but it just seemed a bit weird to mix in so many modules in one giant class... Small classes are usually a good thing :)

Comment: I don't think anybody would disagree with that, but it's also nice to have everything available from one place. After all, something called a Twitter client should be able to do all the Twitter-y client things. Regarding method overwriting, sure, that's a danger.

Answer (score 1):

I think you asked this on IRC too.

The answer provided on IRC was that you get more flexibility with an include-approach, due to the subclass linear cascading inheritance effect - they all need to have a parent.

This shapes the design, as you may recall from IRC - in the case of the subclassing, I gave the example of Sinatra:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
```

Another reason also is that it is convenient to put things into modules, and then re-use it.

Months ago I gave an example of storing my constants in a module called Constants (when I have like more than 50 of these constants) - I simply like to be able to have "iteration points" in my projects that can help identify where I put things. And when I need these constants available in other classes or modules of my code, I simply include that. I can not do the same as easily with subclassing, because subclassing forces me into a more rigid model. And I can only subclass from a class, not a module - but I can include code into a module or a class freely. (This is not a great design point in ruby IMHO - I think extending behaviour should work differently, but I did not design ruby.)

Also the example you gave of Octokit seems hugely bad.

Why not give saner examples like Rack?

Rack does not use many includes at all:

```
    lib/rack/response.rb:     include Helpers
    lib/rack/content_type.rb: include Rack::Utils
    lib/rack/chunked.rb:      include Rack::Utils
```

But you see the examples above are significantly better
for an include-based approach.

Comment: Yes, I did ask the same on IRC before. Well, I understand the difference between mixing in a module and subclassing. The thing that got me a bit confused was that ALL these API wrappers do the same thing -> Mix in a bunch of stuff in ONE class called `Client`. It seems like they are mixing in a lot of different responsibilities into one single class.